# Failing to JOIN ON ST_Contains

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join

I have two tables of polygons: `Table_1`and `Table_2`. All the polygons of `T1`
are inside the polygons of `T2`.

I want to `SELECT` the `id` of `T1` and the name of the polygon from `T2` where the polygon is located.

I am using a spatial join :

```
SELECT T1.id, T2.name
FROM Table_1 AS T1
JOIN Table_2 AS T2
ON ST_Contains(T1.geom, T2.geom)
```

The trouble I have is that the query does not return any value. I don't understand why. I have already used this method for other queries and it worked. Having already done this doesn't help for this case.

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried with `ST_Intersects` and nothing was returned neither.

**UPDATE 2:**

I checked the SRID for the `Table_2`, none was defined. I corrected it but the results are still the same.

**UPDATE 3:**
Here is the geometry of the first row for `Table_1`

```
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
```

The geometries of my `Table_2` have to many characters to fit in the update. The SRID is 2154.

Comment: Because the order matters. If all of the T1s are inside the T2s, then by definition, none of the T1s will contain any T2s, unless, they are alternating in size and getting progressively smaller. So, switch the order in ST_Contains.

Comment: I had already done it and changed nothing, I retried on your advice but still nothing is returned

Comment: Silly question, but how do you know your polygon contains other ? if it's graphically, be carefull with projection system maybe. otherwise, your query should be ok

Comment: the condition WHERE doesn't change anything

Comment: the ST_Dump() function returned this error when I tried to UPDATE my geometries. "Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)"

Comment: Compare SRID: SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom) from Table_1 and  SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom) from Table_2

Comment: The SRID are the same, what do you mean by "Both constructs work correctly" ? Is it working on your side ?

Comment: Both have 2154 as SRID and are Multipolygons

Comment: Everything works correctly for me ...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, the source from which I had received `Table_2` was supposed to give it in the SRID `2154` but it did in `4326`. I had then imported the layer with the SRID as `2154` whereas it wasn't. 
After reprojection of the layer and re-importation under Postgis, the initial query worked.

**ANSWER: ALWAYS CHECK SRID EVEN WHEN IT IS ASSUMED TO BE KNOWN**